# Cannot launch or install app on ios Simulator , even after build and bundle success

Tags: xcode, react-native, macos-high-sierra, react-native-cli

I have been using react-native-cli to create and test app on linux, But recently i switched to mac with High Sierra. I installed Xcode properly and its command line. and every thing as required to run a project on mac.

I create a new project using `react-native init AwesomeProject` and it was successfully created , but when i run `react-native run-ios` it compiles and bundle successfully and opens iOS simulator. But the app doesnot installs nor it launches on the simulator. I am sharing screenshot of what I get in terminal and Simulator. Please Help

[image: ScreenShot of my terminal]

Comment: Try to run the project through xcode, it typically is better at giving you the errors you need to fix. click on AwesomeProject/ios/.....xcodeproj to open xcode. Then press the 'play icon'

Comment: Is it a public project on GitHub or something? If so, which one? I noticed with the line `Launching org.reactjs.native.example.Aws`

Comment: No its not a github project i have created it on local machine using react-native-cli @diogenesgg

Comment: In Xcode , it shows no error and displays running successfully, but nothing happens on ios simulator @GavinThomas

Comment: That green bar set to 100% on console indicates the App opened somewhere somehow. Is it even installed on the ios simulator?

Comment: Same issue here. Any news about that?

Comment: @LucianoKrebs , Yes I fixed it by uninstalling the Xcode and its Cli and homebrew. and Install all the installation procedure again. Main things you need to remember is that when you install the Xcode Cli you have accept the privacy policy which I was missing . So when you accept that agreement. Issue is fixed.. Cli installation done from homebrew .